# How to display two substring from a line?

Tags: grep

How can we find two substrings within a line in particular order using grep?

For example:

```
grep -c "word1" | grep -r "word2" logs
```

gives if string has both word1 and word2. I am looking for string which has "... word1.... word2..."

Comment: Many will disagree with my point of view... but... I think instead of learning dozens of cryptic command line tools, it is more beneficial to learn 1 scripting language, such as Python or Common Lisp or Ruby or whatever (not Perl! lol) instead. Benefit: Smoother learning curve and you can expand your skills over time beyond what those command line tools can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Try a regex in grep like `grep -E "word1.*word2"`

```
$ echo -e 'both word1 and word2. \nI hich\n has "... word1.... word2..."' | grep -E "word1.*word2"
both word1 and word2. 
 has "... word1.... word2..."
```

You may need a better regex to match exactly the words, but that is not your question.